# Why don't we mention all the forces while trying to calculate surface tension?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, surface-tension

I was reading my class notes on Surface Tension and came across this figure:

[image]

And I was wondering why have we just mentioned two forces and not all the other forces like this:

[image]

Then, I realised that we do a somewhat similar thing while mentioning tension across pulley as well.

Why don't we mention all the other forces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the pulley example you just described, if we have a rope thrown over the top of the pulley, and that rope is in contact with the entire top half of the pulley, we begin to pull the rope to one side, accelerating the system. At every point $x$ in the rope there is some associated force of tension $T(x)$

Remember what the tension in the rope looks like, at every point $x$ the rope feels a "pull" from both sides with force equal to $T(x)$

Now assuming no slipping, the tension in the rope causes a torque on the pulley, or you could just think of it as a force at a distance. Let us see what the effects of that torque will be when we add up all of the effects from every point of contact.

Notice at $\textbf{almost}$ every point of contact of the rope and the pulley where there is a "pull right" there is also an equal "pull left" infinitely close to it, and so they cancel out as vectors when we add them. Notice how I said almost, that is because the only two points of contact between the rope and the sphere which don't have their effects cancel out automatically are the endpoints of the rope (this is because there is nothing to their left/right to cancel them).

Therefore the following F.B.D. describing the setup we just discussed has only the tensions at the endpoints of the rope-pulley contact matter. This same principle can be applied to other kinds of tension.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I got what you mean in this example. But this works because the rope has an endpoint. But there's no such thing in the water surface. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @satyamkumarjha The rope doesnt really have an "endpoint" it has an endpoint in its contact with the pulley. In that same way with the surface of ware (or a trampoline) there is a point where the contact between the ball and the trampoline ends, that is where the effect of tension on the body shows itself. At all other points you get the same vector cancellation (except in real life its 3D vectors and in this example it was 2D)